# How to post 1 line story to user's wall

Tags: php, facebook

I've been looking but can't seem to find an answer for this. What I want to do is this:

on mywebsite.com a user clicks a button

this button sends a message to facebook ("Soandso has clicked the button")

I want facebook to then post a 1 line story to that user's wall "* So and so clicked a button!"

Now, I've tried using stream.publish, but I'm not really sure that's what I want because I don't want the user to have to be logged in to click the button. I just want them to tether their account once and then whenever they log in after that, be able to click the button and have it update.

What do you guys think? What do you think could do that in the api?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't publish without user interaction unless a user is connected with their Facebook account.

Depending on what you're looking to do I think you're either looking for FB.Connect.streamPublish or FB.Connect.showFeedDialog.